# Were there two endings to Conan the Barbarian?

Tags: continuity, conan-the-barbarian-1982

Recently I watched *Conan the Barbarian* (the '82 film) on Blu-ray. In the final scene, when Conan sneaks into the temple to kill Thulsa Doom, the princess that Conan and company stole away from Doom earlier comes with Conan and helps him infiltrate the temple by distracting several guards.

In all previous times I saw this movie, I remember Conan going to the temple alone. Was this an alternate ending?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct.  Different takes were used on Conan approaching Thulsa Doom's pulpit between the U. S. and international releases.  In the American edit, they used only takes in which Valerie Quennessen, playing the princess, did not appear.  So you would have seen the U. S. version first, then watched the international release on Blu-ray just recently.

The differences are explained and some of the shots compared, in this YouTube video.